# Non-const function _fastcall TStrings::GetCount() called for const object

Tags: c++, constants, c++builder

I have a old c++ code, wirited and compiled into c++ builder 5. 
But now, I need to update/migrate this code to c++ builder 2009. So, I have some problems:

```
int __fastcall TAllConversor::ListToStr(
    const TStringList* pList,
    AnsiString& strValue,
    const long lngLimiteInferior,
    const long lngLimiteSuperior) const
{
  long lngIndice;
  AnsiString strAux;

  try
  {
    if (lngLimiteSuperior == 0)
      lngIndice = pList->Count;
    else
      lngIndice = lngLimiteSuperior + lngLimiteInferior;

    for (int i = lngLimiteInferior; i < lngIndice; i++)
    {
      strAux += pList->Strings[i] + ";";
    }

    strValue = strAux;
    return 1;
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

At line "lngIndice = pList->Count;" I get this error: "E2522 Non-const function _fastcall TStrings::GetCount() called for const object".

So, how can I solve (work around) it?

Comment: In this code, I have not seen anything about "TStrings::GetCount()" ? Where did you called ? From error, I understand declaration and definition of function is not match or function is called with const object but you should not do. Answer : use Casting

Comment: We need to see some info about TStringList as that is probably incorrect and that is the code change to make

Comment: @gcc: `TStringList` is a VCL class. Its `Count` property calls the `GetCount()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would help if you provided an exact definition of TStringList but I'll just assume it's a templatized array for the typename TString.

Work-around could be to cast away the const, as in:

```
lngIndice = (const_cast<TStringList*>(pList))->Count;
```

Of course it's just what it is - a work-around and you may want to look at providing a const-correct access function in TString itself instead

Comment: you assume incorrectly about what `TStringList` is.  It is not a templated class.  It is a Borland VCL class written in Delphi. But your solution is still valid. The `GetCount()` method is not declared as `const` (and that cannot be changed), so the `pList` parameter needs to have its constness removed to avoid the compiler error, either via `const_cast` or by simply removing the `const` from the `pList` parameter (Delphi is not as const-correct as C++ can be).

Comment: you are going to have the same problem accessing the `pList->Strings[]` property - it calls the `TStrings::Get()` method, which is not declared as `const` either, so you will have to remove the constness on that call as well.